Bitmap image on button using MFC 2.5 dialog application
I've seen the other threads on this topic, but none of them work with MFC 2.5 since
CButton::ModifyStyle() and CButton::SetBitmap() do not exist in MFC 2.5.
I'm making a dialog application using a Resource Editor to create a dialog with several buttons.  The buttons are set to Owner Draw in the Editor.  I'm using the following code:
void CMainDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
  // to do:  initialization
  CBitmapButton m_Processor;
  m_Processor.AutoLoad( IDC_CPU, this );

  return TRUE;
}

The above code should have automatically loaded the bitmap resource I have created as IDB_CPU.  However, on compile the button location just shows a blank space rather than loading the bitmap.
I have also tried this code:
void CMainDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
  // to do:  initialization
  CBitmapButton m_Processor;
  m_Processor.LoadBitmaps( IDB_CPU, NULL, NULL, NULL );

  return TRUE;
}

But it produces the same result with just a blank space.  I know the image exists in the bitmap (I can open it with Paint, for example), and I've verified the resource ID for IDB_CPU is properly set in the resource.h file.
Any help is appreciated!

AutoLoad attempts to load bitmaps by name (not by ID). The resource names are derived from the button text (e.g. "OK") plus a literal suffix of "U", "D", "F", and "X" for the up/down/focus/disabled states. For this to work your resource script must define those bitmaps with a name. Regardless, if your buttons show up empty, the issue is most likely with your owner-draw code (which we cannot see). A [mcve] is required.

You can call LoadBitmap() with at least the 1st argument set. And in this case the resource name(s) do not need to conform to the aforementioned spec. You may need to use MAKEINTRESOURCE() for using a resource ID. The CBitmapButton class instance must not be deleted (so it should not be defined in a function either), it must live throughout the dialog's lifespan. So it must be defined in the class, associated with the resource ID with DDX_Control() in DoDataExchange(), and you must call LoadBitmaps() in OnInitDialog() (after the base-class OnInitDialog() call).

Looks like m_Processor is (or at least should be) a member of class CMainDialog.
The m_ prefix hints that it you indeed have such a member, and if not it should be added.
However, this line inside CMainDialog::OnInitDialog():
CBitmapButton m_Processor;

Declares a local variable. It shadows a member with the same name (if exists).
The bitmap is loaded into this local variable and discarded when it goes out of scope when the method returns, instead of into the dialog member which is shown in the GUI (assuming that there is such a member).
Therefore you should remove this line.

This gave me a hint that I'm doing it wrong, being a n00b and all.  I was able to figure out how to make m_Processor a member of class CMainDialog, but the Class Express wizard would only allow me to make of type CButton rather than CBitmapButton.  Rather odd to me if the compiler supports CBitmapButton types.  I'll have to Google some and see if I can figure out how to change the type.

@CharlieDobson I am not sure how this should be done, hope you find via googling. You can post a new question regarding this issue. But I am quite sure what I wrote is the answer to your current question as posted.

Try just changing the variable type from CButton to CBitmapButton in the class definition.

I had to do a combination of both your suggestions to get it to work.  I needed to remove the local variable in CMainDialog::OnInitDialog() as well as manually changing the class type from CButton to CBitmapButton.  I also had to not use the wizard to add the member variable, rather add it under the protected: specifier in the dialog class.

This isn't the most common way to associate Win32 controls to MFC class-variables. Instead, you can use the Class Wizard to add member variables to your dialog class.
As for your problem (using an old MFC version, lacking the CButton::SetBitmap() method), one would say use the latest VS/MFC Version, but this is not always easy. The workaround is use the Win32 BM_SETIMAGE message instead. MFC is for the most part a MFC wrapper (and a quite "thin" one, I would say). And this is exactly what MFC actually does. Below is the implementation of CButton::SetBitmap(), in file afxwin2.inl, line 640:
_AFXWIN_INLINE HBITMAP CButton::SetBitmap(HBITMAP hBitmap)
    { ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd)); return (HBITMAP)::SendMessage(m_hWnd, BM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hBitmap); }

That is, it just sends the BM_SETIMAGE to the control. You can do the same in your application:
SendDlgItemMessage(IDC_MYBUTTON, BM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hBitmap);

OR
SendDlgItemMessage(IDC_MYBUTTON, BM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)(HBITMAP)m_Bitmap);

The CBitmap class has HBITMAP operator, therefore you can pass the CBitmap instance variable where a HBITMAP is expected; however the SendMessage()/SendDlgItemMessage() takes an LPARAM as the last argument, so an extra (HBITMAP) cast is needed here.

The BM_SETIMAGE and IMAGE_BITMAP messages do not appear to be supported by the Win16 API.  I tried the following code, but my compiler said both were unidentified:
{
  CDialog::OnInitDialog()

  // to do:  initialization
  CBitmap h_bitmap;
  h_bitmap.LoadBitmap( IDB_CPU );
  ::SendDlgItemMessage( IDC_PROCESSR, BM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)(HBITMAP)h_bitmap );
  h_bitmap.DeleteObject();

  return TRUE;
}```

Sorry for the poor formatting above.  I ran out of edit time before I could fix it.

If the only problem is that these symbols are not defined it's easy, BM_SETIMAGE is 0x00F7 and IMAGE_BITMAP is 0. The question is if they are supported by the OS control library. Try it with the above constants. From the header files it turns out that they are supported since Win NT 4.0, but you can give it a try. I wouldn't delete the bitmap (better instantiate the CBitmap object in your class, not in OnInitDialog() as it is allocated in the stack, and the destructor will delete it anyway), at least until I made sure that it's no longer needed (after calling BM_SETIMAGE).

Forgot to mention, the button must not be owner-drawn, for these to work.
